# Use of iloc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying some coding as practice where I found the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv',usecols=[1,2,3,4])
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```

I am not able to understand what the second statement is doing. I tried to read the documentation for [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) but am not able to understand the purpose of it.

Please help me understand the reason behind the usage of second line in the code.

Comment: This will reverse the order of dataframe, iloc works like slicing and -1 means to traverse in backward direction

Comment: The syntax is akin to Python list or NumPy array slicing. I've marked this a duplicate which explains in more detail. If this is not sufficient, let me know and I can reopen if you can explain specifically the problem.

Comment: Looks like a line to reverse the data. But I think it could be done differently

Comment: Does it means that it reverses the last column values of the `df`? or it reverse the coumns of teh `df`?

Comment: @JafferWilson, `df.iloc[x]` or `df.iloc[x, :]` slices by row only, `df.iloc[:, y]` slices by column only, `df.iloc[x, y]` slices by row & column.

Comment: @jpp Nah .. the question you have suggested is related to slicing of the arrays. But my question is related to `iloc`. What for it is? I can understand that it is dealing with the last value as the statement`[::-1]` but why with `iloc`?

Comment: @JafferWilson, Why *not* with `iloc`? The same syntax can be used across lists, arrays, dataframe indexers. This should be *expected*, not unusual.